# create and manage authentication token tomcat

Tags: oauth, token, jwt

How may I create the an access token for my RestFul Api deployed on TomCat?
I have to use it to validate the access of an android application.
Should I use some framework, or doing it by myself?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 and OpenID COnnect are:

- Open Standards
- Widely deployed
- Well Tested in Real-Life and in labs
- Have many libraries and documented code examples

And these are cryptographic and security protocols.

Why would you try to reinvent the wheel?

-jim